# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android

I have tried every solution provided by google.
 Nothing solves my problem. I have upgrade the android studio to latest version available. I have add different dependencies but nothing works.
I am in desperate need of solution.

Comment: You will need to provide more details to get useful answers. For example, it seems that you have a dependency resolution problem, but you don't explain what dependency it's failing on, what your build environment is, how the exception (if any) thrown looks etc etc. More context and perhaps a relevant snippet of the dependency declaration etc will make it possible for people to give you relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded studio, try adding what ever the

```
buildTypes{
      debug{ ... }
      release{ ... }
}
```

you have in your (app) build.gradle file, You have to include all the buildTypes{ } with same names as like

```
buildTypes{
  debug{ ... }
  release{ ... }
}
```

in build.gradle files of All libraries/modules included in project.

clean and rebuild the project, the issue will be fixed.

Still issue not fixed, update the gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Hope it helps!